# Where can I find the primefaces tag library documentation?

Tags: jsf-2, documentation, primefaces

Where can I find primefaces tag library documentation such as this: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/docs/tag/index.html ?

I already have the jar, the sources of the primefaces. The apidoc supplied is "primefaces 2.2.RC2 API", not the "Tag Library Documentation Generator - Generated Documentation"

Maybe I should try generating it from the source, or maybe from the JAR (although I think the javadocs are not in the bytecodes) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here lies the [answer](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6758&p=27684p27684)

> ethermion : Descriptions were dropped for 2.2. Nothing to do with Netbeans. It is what you've got.
>
> optimus.prime : Descriptions will only be available in documentation to promote the PrimeFaces User's Guide 2.2.

And [this is another thread](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6804)  started by me

Comment: @Laurent.B Pay attention when you're making edits! Who approves this crap?

Answer (score 2):

The best that I could find is the User guide, in which you could find the whole elements with his characteristics

http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_2_2.pdf

Comment: This was already been answered by Albert Kam. Please keep in mind that until some months ago, the PrimeFaces User Guide was not freely available for download, you had to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

Since shortly, PrimeFaces has new tag library and API documentation. See also this [blog entry](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1862).

> PrimeFaces API and VDL Docs are now available online. These are additional resources to the reference user’s guide.
>
> For Primefaces v.3.5 :
>
> - [API Docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/)
> - [VDL Docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/)
>
> P.S. Thanks to PrimeFaces Users BalusC and Arjan Tijms for their great work on [VDL Doc generator](http://vdldoc.omnifaces.org)!

---

**Update**: for other/newer versions (as of now, 3.4, 3.5, 4.0 and 5.0 are available), just browse the root folder of docs:

- [All API Docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/)
- [All VDL Docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/)

Answer (score 1):

if you need .tld file, you can find one in jar: in META-INF folder. It is called primefaces-i.tld

Comment: Hello. I can get all the attributes from eclipse helios' auto complete inside a jsf page. What i need is the description of those attributes.

Comment: this tld contains the description of the components. I don't know why eclipse doesn't show it to you. my Idea does.

Comment: Well, i've checked the tld files, they all contains empty description tags. I think that's why eclipse is showing nothing when doing content assist.

Comment: I think you've got some wrong version of primefaces jar. Try to download the new one from the website.

Comment: I just finished downloading the file. Both the jar file, or the jar file inside the bundle has these info : the file name is : primefaces-2.2.RC2.jar, and the file size is : 1743812. And i've checked the tld, still no descriptions available.

Comment: this http://repository.prime.com.tr/org/primefaces/primefaces/2.0.2/primefaces-2.0.2.jar has all the descriptions in place. I think RC2 has wrong tld file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a separate JAR on the download page that contains the source code, and you could use the [taglibrarydoc tool](https://taglibrarydoc.dev.java.net/) to generate the documentation from that.

I don't think you'll find a premade tag library documentation for an RC (release candidate) version.

Comment: The tool is very helpful. But to my shock, the descriptions are not there in the TLDs. Perhaps it's still in RC version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the statement to the same question from another user:

optimus.prime:

Javadocs are bundled with zip packages, but for latest 2.2.M1 it is not available. You can use 2.1's bundle to get javadocs though.

With upcoming 2.2.RC1, java and tag docs will be available via bundles distributions.

Look at http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4575

Answer (score 0):

Now the Solution of adding the primefaces Tag Library is in the User guides 3.xx  edition itself and we can implement it with the updated Tag library as

```
html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html