# How to enable javadoc for primefaces elements?

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, primefaces

I started using primefaces a few months ago, and I couldn'd find out a way to enable javadoc for primefaces. Now I want to know if there's really a way to do that and how to do ?

Thanks in advance,
Leo

PS: I'm using Netbeans7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This link](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13347) (regarding tablib docs) and [this other link](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13439) (regarding user manual) might help. I don't think the taglib documentation is included in the JAR yet, but their lead developer says it will be. He also says that the user manual is now free (used to cost 10 euro).

[This forums post](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13808) may also be of interest to you if you are using a PrimeFaces 3.0-M3-SNAPSHOT release.

This issue was also discussed in [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498539/where-can-i-find-the-primefaces-tag-library-documentation) about the older PrimeFaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Jim. I'll check the links that you passed! C'ya

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be bundle the source and binary jar into a library via Tools -> Library -> new library and then registering this library in your application (Right click project -> properties -> Libraries -> add Library)

However I don't think this is going to help you, as I don't really see any comments in the few classes that I looked at, nor do I see a javadocs jar. So your best bet is probably the [user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).